# TFS 2018 scrumboard hang when moving task to In progress lane

Tags: tfs

Can anyone tell us why our TFS 2018 (update 3) scrumboard hangs when moving task from "To do" to "In progress". It seems that the "In progress" lane is not automatically re-freshed.

It's working fine when tasks are moved between Todo and Done both ways.

Se the screendump below:

[image]

Comment: Have you ever customized the process template related to the transitions? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa337653(v=vs.80) for details.  Reference this blog : [Modifying Work Item States and Transitions](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/09/23/modifying-work-item-states.aspx)

Comment: Hi thank for our answer. It seems that when i remove the Action = Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork and field =* Assigned To  from WIT flow it works. But not when i add these. Does this values not exist in TFS 2018? How to I define a field action for assigning the current user who move the task from to do - In progress?